# React Wait until transition end for vertical scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, css-transitions

I'm trying to make vertical scroll page looks like fullpage.js with react

https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Page scroll works well but having hard time to prevent double scroll..

I want to make scroll doesn't work until finish move to next page.

Using setTimeout and clearTimeout works well but it has pre delay before moving pages.

I don't like that so tried to use onTransitionEnd to detect change but doesn't work well.

Currently my code is like this

```
const Container = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isAnimating, setAnimating] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const animatingRef = useRef(false);
  const indexRef = useRef(0);
  indexRef.current = index;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAnimating) {
      const updater = (e: WheelEvent) => {
        setAnimating(true);
        let dir = e.deltaY;
        if (dir < 0) {
          indexRef.current > 0 && setIndex(indexRef.current - 1);
        } else {
          indexRef.current < 2 && setIndex(indexRef.current + 1);
        }
      };
      window.addEventListener('wheel', e => updater(e));
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('wheel', e => updater(e));
      };
    }
  }, [isAnimating]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current) {
      ref.current.style.transition = 'all 0.5s ease-in-out';
      ref.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0,-${index * 100}%,0)`;
    }
  }, [index]);
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ViewContainer ref={ref} onTransitionEnd={() => setAnimating(false)}>
        <View color="orange" />
        <View color="red" />
        <View color="yellow" />
      </ViewContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```